# How to best assign choices to CPT posts and allow filtering on frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

Looking for suggestions on how best to achieve my goals for assigning filters to posts and using those when searching for service providers.

I have created a CPT: Service Providers
I want to allow Service Providers to select the categories they provide services within
e.g. Region - select which regions you operate in
Ages - what age groups do you service

I then want to have a selection process like here: https://www.shelterme.org.au/ where the user selects multiple categories that filter results down to providers who fit within the selected groups.

I was thinking about CPT taxonomies but I am wondering if there is a better solution, e.g. ACF or something.
I need to be able to filter search results using these fields so I am not sure how to best approach it.

Looking for ideas and thoughts from anyone who may have done something similar